# Is it possible to apply type overloading to a class while retaining the class's type?

Tags: typescript

Not sure if the question title makes sense but essentially if I have a class that looks like

```js
class Foo {}
```

I can create functions that take/return `Foo` as an argument using

```
function bar(foo: Foo): Foo {}
```

However if I overload my class by assigning it via a type declaration I can no longer use `Foo` as a type directly.

```js
type FooConstructor = {
  new(): {}
  new <T0>(v1: T0): {}
}

const Foo: FooConstructor = class { }

// 'Foo' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
function bar(foo: Foo) { }

const foo = new Foo()
bar(foo)
```

How can I apply my overloaded types while retaining the ability to use the type directly?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAwnAdgZ2AJwK4GNhyZQC8UA3gLABQUUKEA7gBQCUAXOQL7W30NQAeACoAGAHxMAbgEYOo9l2rcq1XKgywEHeEnVY8BIqVwAbAIZo05KMuoAzbCnwBLVFABGZzEztbNcFmtbKjV0YChfOBI6Rn9Wak9vSJYgA)

Answer (score 0):

The class name in typescript represents two things:

1. When used in an expression, it represents the constructor (ie the value) used at runtime to instantiate the class
2. When used in a type annotation, it represents the instance type of the class.

When you use a constant typed as a constructor, you are only defining one of these two things, the value part. You need to define a type with the same name to get a similar effect to what class does:

```
const Foo: FooConstructor = class { }
type Foo = InstanceType<typeof Foo>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=36&pln=5&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAwnAdgZ2AJwK4GNhyZQC8UA3gLABQUUKEA7gBQCUAXOQL7W30NQAeACoAGAHxMAbgEYOo9l2rcq1arlQZYCDvCQaseAkVK4ANgEM0aclGWhIWuCSgBJdMHMpcEIeAgD7CDgAM0cxVSpg7C9gAEtUKAAjc0wmYO1HFhtlNX0odKdSPkdWamTUgpYgA)

Note: I used `InstanceType` to get the type of the instance type, but you can define this type manually, probably you might need to make it generic.